# List All Mp3 files in android 10

Tags: android, mp3, environment, mediastore, android-external-storage

I'm learning android development by developing a music player and I need to read mp3 files on a device. I found this([List All Mp3 files in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461954/list-all-mp3-files-in-android)) question on StackOverflow and used the code from the first answer.

I tested the code on 2 different devices

1. A Samsung that runs **Android 8**
2. A Xiaomi Poco that runs **Android 10**

the code works OK on the Android 8 but I get a `NullPointerException` on Android 10

```
File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles();// this is were I get the NPE
```

1. Is it because Android 10 doesn't allow accessing files this way?
2. If so, is there any other way to get the same thing done on Android 10?

Comment: Query the `MediaStore`, please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39785336/115145